# Array type of an array or contracts?

Tags: solidity, arrays, inheritance

If I have a contract named `LockedOffer`, and in another contract that inherits from `LockedOffer` I declare an array `LockedOffer[] public offers`, what type is the array? I'm assuming it's an address array

Comment: It is an array of LockedOffer instances, not addresses. I believe you can get the address of an individual contract by using address(offeres[i]), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of LocketOffer struct variables.